# Sending to another user with e-mail address

Tags: coinbase-api

I am trying to create a script in Python to transfer funds to another Coinbase user when all I have is an e-mail address. I have been unsuccessful so far. How do I get another user's "id" when all I have is their e-mail address?

As a follow on, can I add a memo/note to the transfer? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out with a little bit more searching and trial and error. For anyone else who may have this question:

First get the account ID for the currency you want to send.

```
account_list = client.get_accounts()['data']
ETH_id = [acc['id'] for acc in account_list if acc['balance']['currency'] == "ETH"][0]
```

Then use the `send_money` function (not `transfer_money`) to send to an e-mail address.

```
client.send_money(ETH_id,to="<e-mail address>", amount="0.0005", currency="ETH", description = "Hey look, it worked.")
```

The `description` keyword is for the memo.